# Solr 4 Spatial Search polygon vs polygon search with distance parameter

Tags: solr, lucene, polygon, distance, spatial

Is there a way to search for a polygon in X distance to indexed polygons?

I already have indexed polygons and multipolygons in SOLR 4.2.1 index with a field type

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
           spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
           distErrPct="0.001"
           maxDistErr="0.000009"
           units="degrees"
        />
```

and I can already do simple intersects queries like

```
fq=geo_location:"Intersects(POLYGON((-0.141964 51.515580, -0.130119 51.516648, -0.129261 51.515900)))"
```

So I need:
search for a POLYGON+distance in an index full of POLYGONS
and
search for a POINT+distance(A circle) in an index full of POLYGONS

Comment: Hi , so one question : How is the response times for solr ? I'm thinking about batch reverserve geocoding using solr+spark. I want't to know If Solr search holds it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point + distance (a circle) is already supported:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4
ex: geo_location:"Intersects(Circle(4.56,1.23 d=0.0710))"

Polygon + distance is buffering a polygon by said distance and then doing standard intersects.  JTS has a Geometry.buffer() operation that is quite easy to use -- it's just a method call.  I hope to one day expose this somehow in Spatial4j (this year likely), which will then be accessible to higher levels -- Solr.  In the mean time, you can use JTS at your client code to buffer the polygon and then submit that polygon to Solr to search.

Keep in mind through all this that JTS works in a 2D space; it doesn't know anything about geodesics (i.e. it doesn't account for the fact that the world is a sphere).  Spatial4j wraps JTS geometries to add dateline wrap support but that's it.  What you *might* want to do is consider using a map projection if all your data is conveniently in one part of the world.  That can greatly reduce some skewing effects.  An example of skewing effects that will occur if you don't do this is that a buffered polygon half way up from the equator to the pole will actually be buffered east-west half as much as it is buffered north-south.  Even if you don't store the points in Solr in some projection, your client could project your query polygon locally (at the center of your polygon), then buffer it, then un-project it back to lat-lon space.  That will dramatically reduce skewing if there is a lot of points on your polygon.  If your query polygon doesn't have many vertices, you could artificially add them.  All the stuff I'm talking about in this paragraph is stuff I hope to add one day so that it's automatic.

Comment: The resolution of the polygons in my original data was ridiculous. I had to "simplify" the polygons by limiting the number of points to 285 and accuracy of the points to 4 decimal digits. In WKT format this gives me a shape with less than 4000 characters.

So I do have a lot of points and my data is conveniently in some parts of the world. UK, Germany, Netherlands and Belgium. I'm not very familiar with "map projection" can you possibly point me to some reading material?

Comment: BTW I ran the query 
geo_location:"Intersects(Circle(-0.141964,51.515580 d=0.0590))"
only a million times with no results, then I realized Circle expects the point in (Latitude, Longitude radius) format so running
geo_location:"Intersects(Circle(51.515580,-0.041964 d=0.010))"
brought me back SOHO successfully and made me happy

Comment: For non-WKT (Circle syntax is a bit of a hack), you can do either "x y" or "y,x".   RE projections, you can use Proj4j to help you project data.  Wikipedia (and Googling it) and you'll find loads of fascinating info about projections. I don't claim to be an expert on that subject; I've not yet had to employ that technique.

Comment: @DavidSmiley - Is there a way to get distance from the original polygon query the author posted?

Comment: No.  I think JTS might have something but you'd need to do some work to leverage it inside Lucene/Solr.